# Add Elements of a 2-Dimensional Array using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

Hey guys I am having problems writing this part of my code. I have to sum up the elements of this 2-dimensional array using recursion. I understand what I need to do but I am not understanding how to implement this to step through the array. I keep receiving errors. Could someone please help me out?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] a;
        a = new int[3][4];
        int sum = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter 12 numbers: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                a[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
        sum = sum2D(a, 0, 0);
        System.out.println("The sum of the array: " + sum);

    }

    public static int sum2D(int a[][], int row, int col) {
        if (row == a.length-1) {
            return a[row][col];
        }

        if (col == a[row].length-1) {
            return a[row][col] + sum2D(a, row++, 0);
        }

        return a[row][col] + sum2D(a, row, col++);
    }

}
```

Comment: You say "without recursion" and then the example you give is a recursive method. Do you actually just want an iterative solution?

Comment: Your example uses recursion (sum2D calls sum2D). So do you already have a 2 dimensional array? And if so, do you simply need to know how to iterate through it using a for-loop?

Comment: I need to add the elements up without using a for loop while loop or any such thing. I have to continue to call the method sum2D to add all the elements up

Comment: In that case you don't mean "without recursion", you mean *with* recursion.

Comment: for loops are "iteration". Calling the function within itself is recursion.

Comment: Then you *want* to use recursion.  Please edit your question to clear things up.  Also, is it a requirement that you have only *one* recursive routine that calls itself?  That makes things overly complex when dealing with a 2-D array.  Or are you allowed to have two?

Comment: I was just going by what my professor had told us. I thought it was recursion but he kept saying it was not recursion so thats why I said it like I did

Comment: StackOverflow needs a way to downvote professors.

Comment: I have no limits on how many recursive routines I can use. I just cannot use any iteration

Comment: I got it, gimmme a sec here...

Comment: @AnubianNoob Should we be handing him his homework answers? Wouldn't it be better to simply show why this code is failing?

Comment: @deworde First off this isn't homework or I would have said it. Second, this is independent study where I missed this problem on an exam and so I wanted to better understand what I was doing. So I would appreciate it stop assuming. I asked for help not answers. Anything anyone gives is helpful.

Comment: @deworde I think his approach is all wrong, so "showing him why this code is failing" is probably not enough.  But yes, giving him the general outline of a correct approach would be much better than handing him an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic plan, when you need a recursive solution, is to look for a way to break down the problem so that it contains a smaller problem (or more than one smaller problem) that looks just like the original problem, only smaller.

For a 2-D array, this can be tricky.  Say your array looks like

```
1    2    3    4    5
6    7    8    9    10
11   12   13   14   15
```

One's first thought might be to write a recursive function that takes a `row` and `column`, and adds `a[row][column]` to the sum of the *rest* of the array.  The problem is that if, for example, `row=0` and `column=0`, the "smaller problem" you have to solve looks like

```
      +---------------------+
    1 |  2    3    4    5   |
  +---+                     |
  | 6    7    8    9    10  |
  | 11   12   13   14   15  |
  +-------------------------+
```

(please excuse the bad ASCII art).  So now your smaller problem doesn't look like an array at all, but some weird polygon.  It's still possible to use this approach, by writing a recursive function like

```
int sumOfWeirdShapedSectionOfArray(int[][] array, int firstRow, int firstCol)
```

But that's definitely an abuse of recursion.  Better would be to break down the array into the "first row" and "the rest of the rows":

```
    1    2    3    4    5
  +-------------------------+
  | 6    7    8    9    10  |
  | 11   12   13   14   15  |
  +-------------------------+
```

(Or you could break it into "the last row" and "the rest of the rows".)

Now, your smaller problem looks a lot like the original problem, right?  So your answer would be that "the sum of the elements in the array is the sum of the first row, plus the sum of the elements in the smaller array starting with the next row".  The second part of this is a recursive call.  The first part, the sum of the first row, would require that you call a new function to add up a row; and since you're still not allowed to use loops, the "add up a row" function would also be recursive, but that should be easy.

Having said all this, nobody would ever use recursion in the real world on this problem.  However, if the point is to get familiar with recursion so that you *can* use it when it's called for, then this sort of thought process is what you need to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the assist! That was put better than what my professor explained. I realized my mistake after it was pointed out but this helps a lot. At least your trying to help my out by giving me some advice instead of being a condescending jerk like some others.

Answer (score 0):

To do it without recursion, just have two nested for loops:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++)
      sum += array[i][j];
return sum;
```

To do it with recursion:

```
int sum2D(int a[][], int row, int col) {

    if (row == a.length-1)
        return a[row][col];

    if(col == a[row].length-1)
        return a[row][col]+sum2D(a,row+1,0);

    return a[row][col]+sum2D(a,row,col+1);
}
```

Basically you're doing the same thing: going through each row and column and adding it together.

However, note that ther *is* a limit on how many recursive routines you can use. If you recurse too deep, you'll get a StackOverflow error.

Comment: So I have a stackoverflowexception at if(row == a.length).

Comment: @osiris2190 How large is your array? Or wait did I forget to subtract one... EDIT: Yeah, it should be a.length-1

Comment: my array is array[3][4] where the user enters 12 integer elements if that helps with the problem.

Comment: I posted the updated code including the main function. Still gives me the error

Comment: @osiris2190 Fixed it. The issue is that you can't use `row++` or `col++`. You need to use `row+1` or `col+1`.

Comment: was the ++ not allowing it to increase the row/col properly?

Comment: @AnubianNoob ++row would probably also work, but yeah, row and col ideally never change.

Comment: @osiris2190 `row++` increments the variable _after_ pasing it into the method. You could do `++row`, but that needlessly changes the value of `row`. `row+1` is a best solution.

Comment: @osiris2190 row++ means the value submitted to the function is still "row". So you basically end up calling the same function again with the same values, and then do that again, and again and again andagainandagainandagai...STACK OVERFLOW ERROR.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0):

The base condition was wrong in the above code:

Here is the code that works:

```
 public static int addMatrix(int a[][],int r,int c){
    if(r==a.length-1 && c==a[r].length-1)
        return a[r][c];
    if(c==a[r].length-1)
        return a[r][c]+addMatrix(a,r+1,0);
    return a[r][c]+addMatrix(a,r,c+1);  
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Equivalent "C" program here, but for number of Rows 4 and Number of columns 1 , I get unpredictable result why?

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <conio.h>
   int row,col;
   main()
   {


    int a[][];
    int nrow,ncols,summ = 0;
    printf("Enter No of Rows:");
    scanf("%d",&nrow);
    printf("Enter No of Columns:");
    scanf("%d",&ncols);
    int arraylength,rowlength;

     printf("Enter %d numbers: \n",nrow*ncols);
     for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    arraylength=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
    summ = sum(a,0, 0,nrow,ncols);
    printf("\n The sum of the array: %d ",summ);
    getch();

   }

   int sum( int a[row][col],int row,int col,int RowLen,int ColLen)
   {

    if ((row == RowLen-1) && (col==(ColLen)-1)) {
        return a[row][col];
    }

    if (col == (ColLen)-1)
    {             
        return (a[row][col] + sum(a,row+1,0,RowLen,ColLen));
    }

       return (a[row][col] + sum(a,row, col+1,RowLen,ColLen));
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a question rather than an answer. Perhaps ask a new question?

Comment: I got the answer for my question by myself trying, "C"(may be some compiler) does not support passing two dimensional variable array as formal parameters. So in the above "C" code, I needed to remove  int a[row][col] in function sum and changed it to have pass column length alone which is fixed. Here it is : int sum( int m,int n,int a[][n],int row,int col). m is row length and n is column length both are fixed.